# Configuring Shim signed

Tags: updates, update-manager

While doing a software update (currently using 16.04),
everything in the window went grey during install, and is apparently stuck on "configuring shim-signed".
I am not wanting to cancel installation...is this just a matter of patience? How long should I wait?
What should I do?

Comment: Take a look at [my post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/971240/dpkg-error-processing-package-shim-signed/971290#971290)

Answer (score 0):

I had to end the Software Updater and reboot, then use terminal to do `sudo apt-get update`

Then, I also followed the instructions to run `dpkg --configure -a`

After that, I did `sudo apt-get update` again, followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade`

This worked for me, but I'm not saying definitively that this will fix your issue as well.