# dpkg: error processing package shim-signed, locked by another process error

Tags: apt, dpkg, update-manager, secure-boot

I just ran the Software Updater (on Ubuntu 16.04).
While installing the new packages (including a new kernel version) I got a Grub Secure Boot alert.
After that the Software Updater crashed. 
It stuck at post-installation-triggers on shim-signed.

After having killed all processes related to dpkg I tried to configure it again

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

which returned the following:

```
Setting up shim-signed (1.32~16.04.1+0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
shim-signed
```

I fear that if I restart I'll have problems with booting. Can I reconfigure shim-signed, or can I revert the update somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently after the command

```
sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*.dat
```

and an overall reconfiguration of dpkg, shim-signed has been fixed.
I just booted and everything seems fine...

Comment: worked for me, thanks!
(fixed my apt update, that is, the original problem still exists)