# After clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 I get shim-signed error

Tags: 14.04

I know that this is known bug and there are multiple questions on the same error, but unfortunately non of the answers helped resolved my problem.

I come from a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04.05 Desktop 64bit. I did clean install with the option of "Erasing the disk and install Ubuntu" but no matter how many times I tried to clean install Ubuntu (currently 3 times), whenever I login to the system and I try to run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 shim-signed : Depends: shim (= 13-0ubuntu2) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Running `sudo apt-get -f install` I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  shim
The following NEW packages will be installed
  shim
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 411 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/440 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,448 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/shim_13-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/shim_13-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/shim_13-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Few notes:

- I tried to install Ubuntu with clean install multiple times, I even tried with different USB sticks (so the USB stick is not corrupted) and I tried to install Ubuntu on another machine with the same stick and it worked.
- I suspect that the problem is with my file system (or even Grub?) somehow.
- It's not the first time I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on this computer, in the past I didn't have such problems with this computer.
- I tried the following solutions so far:

  - [Error processing package shim-signed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948315/error-processing-package-shim-signed)
  - [dpkg: error processing package shim-signed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971240/dpkg-error-processing-package-shim-signed)
  - [Errors during upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 (shim-signed and grub-efi-amd64-signed)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031066/errors-during-upgrade-from-17-10-to-18-04-shim-signed-and-grub-efi-amd64-signed/1032156#1032156)

## Output of the file `/etc/fstab`

Here is the output of `cat /etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=e0f60d28-02c8-40e7-b014-aedd69a1577b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=BAF1-4AA1  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
#UUID=b34bcda0-da7d-4155-a603-43f8f262f562 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

## Check disk for defects

I reboot the system with the live USB stick and I chose the option "to check the disk for defects" it run for a while and it said that there was an error to 1 of the files or something like this, it didn't said which file and what the error was and it asked me to reboot. I reboot but the problem is still there.

## Output of `sudo fsck -f /`

- I boot to the GRUB menu.
- Chose "Advanced Options" -> "Recovery Mode" -> "Root Access"
- I typed `sudo fsck -f /` and the reboot (output of the command below).

Output of `sudo fsck -f /`:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda2: 216775/59981824 files (0.1% non-contiguous), 4881222/239906048 blocks.
```

## Output of `ls -lAR /boot`

Output of running `ls -lAR /boot`:

```
/boot:
total 107832
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1251923 Aug 28 18:22 abi-4.4.0-135-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1240067 Jul 13  2016 abi-4.4.0-31-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   190632 Aug 28 18:22 config-4.4.0-135-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   189566 Jul 13  2016 config-4.4.0-31-generic
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Jan  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     4096 Sep 18 10:35 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 35931131 Sep 18 10:34 initrd.img-4.4.0-135-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 35233299 Sep 18 10:34 initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   176500 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178176 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178680 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      255 Aug 28 18:22 retpoline-4.4.0-135-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3918274 Aug 28 18:22 System.map-4.4.0-135-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3879360 Jul 13  2016 System.map-4.4.0-31-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7064752 Aug 28 18:22 vmlinuz-4.4.0-135-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7066680 Sep 18 10:34 vmlinuz-4.4.0-135-generic.efi.signed
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6937248 Sep 18 10:32 vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6939160 Aug  3  2016 vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic.efi.signed

/boot/efi:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep 18 09:08 EFI

/boot/efi/EFI:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  2  2017 ubuntu

/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu:
total 3240
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     126 Sep 18 09:35 grub.cfg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  958328 Sep 18 09:35 grubx64.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1153336 Sep 14 09:56 mmx64.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1196736 Sep 18 09:35 shimx64.efi

/boot/grub:
total 2384
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Sep 18 10:35 fonts
-r--r--r-- 1 root root    8169 Sep 18 10:35 grub.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1024 Sep 18 10:36 grubenv
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Sep 18 10:35 locale
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2405285 Sep 18 10:35 unicode.pf2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   12288 Sep 18 10:35 x86_64-efi

/boot/grub/fonts:
total 2352
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2405285 Sep 18 10:35 unicode.pf2

/boot/grub/locale:
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1032 Sep 18 10:35 en_AU.mo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  587 Sep 18 10:35 en_CA.mo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4464 Sep 18 10:35 en_GB.mo

/boot/grub/x86_64-efi:
total 3264
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  17032 Sep 18 10:35 acpi.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1928 Sep 18 10:35 adler32.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8624 Sep 18 10:35 affs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8768 Sep 18 10:35 afs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  23512 Sep 18 10:35 ahci.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1017 Sep 18 10:35 all_video.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1512 Sep 18 10:35 aout.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5088 Sep 18 10:35 appleldr.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4736 Sep 18 10:35 archelp.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8984 Sep 18 10:35 ata.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7424 Sep 18 10:35 at_keyboard.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2512 Sep 18 10:35 backtrace.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10152 Sep 18 10:35 bfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3144 Sep 18 10:35 bitmap.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5160 Sep 18 10:35 bitmap_scale.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3216 Sep 18 10:35 blocklist.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3304 Sep 18 10:35 boot.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  49984 Sep 18 10:35 bsd.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  19720 Sep 18 10:35 btrfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2896 Sep 18 10:35 bufio.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4256 Sep 18 10:35 cat.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5472 Sep 18 10:35 cbfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6376 Sep 18 10:35 cbls.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3848 Sep 18 10:35 cbmemc.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1624 Sep 18 10:35 cbtable.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4072 Sep 18 10:35 cbtime.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8552 Sep 18 10:35 chain.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4728 Sep 18 10:35 cmdline_cat_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2888 Sep 18 10:35 cmp.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3593 Sep 18 10:35 command.lst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3504 Sep 18 10:35 configfile.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 124416 Sep 18 10:35 core.efi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4384 Sep 18 10:35 cpio_be.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4384 Sep 18 10:35 cpio.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2544 Sep 18 10:35 cpuid.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2120 Sep 18 10:35 crc64.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  16200 Sep 18 10:35 cryptodisk.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    936 Sep 18 10:35 crypto.lst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6920 Sep 18 10:35 crypto.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3888 Sep 18 10:35 cs5536.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2976 Sep 18 10:35 datehook.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3192 Sep 18 10:35 date.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1936 Sep 18 10:35 datetime.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  13680 Sep 18 10:35 diskfilter.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3128 Sep 18 10:35 disk.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5792 Sep 18 10:35 div_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2688 Sep 18 10:35 dm_nv.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3024 Sep 18 10:35 echo.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2272 Sep 18 10:35 efifwsetup.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  13448 Sep 18 10:35 efi_gop.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7040 Sep 18 10:35 efinet.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7496 Sep 18 10:35 efi_uga.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25544 Sep 18 10:35 ehci.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7232 Sep 18 10:35 elf.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2184 Sep 18 10:35 eval.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8544 Sep 18 10:35 exfat.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2280 Sep 18 10:35 exfctest.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8736 Sep 18 10:35 ext2.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7088 Sep 18 10:35 extcmd.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8680 Sep 18 10:35 fat.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  24512 Sep 18 10:35 file.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3000 Sep 18 10:35 fixvideo.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  17688 Sep 18 10:35 font.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3784 Sep 18 10:35 fshelp.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    214 Sep 18 10:35 fs.lst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 118520 Sep 18 10:35 functional_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2416 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_arcfour.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9688 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_blowfish.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  30400 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_camellia.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  15336 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_cast5.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3904 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_crc.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  17248 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_des.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3440 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_dsa.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4144 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_idea.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4152 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_md4.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4952 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_md5.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3312 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_rfc2268.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  20272 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_rijndael.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9136 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_rmd160.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3400 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_rsa.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  13336 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_seed.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  16488 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_serpent.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7888 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_sha1.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6120 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_sha256.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7480 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_sha512.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  13576 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_tiger.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  33944 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_twofish.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  23088 Sep 18 10:35 gcry_whirlpool.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9104 Sep 18 10:35 geli.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8600 Sep 18 10:35 gettext.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  61200 Sep 18 10:35 gfxmenu.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4680 Sep 18 10:35 gfxterm_background.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7848 Sep 18 10:35 gfxterm_menu.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18440 Sep 18 10:35 gfxterm.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5128 Sep 18 10:35 gptsync.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 124416 Sep 18 10:35 grub.efi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11824 Sep 18 10:35 gzio.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6544 Sep 18 10:35 halt.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8616 Sep 18 10:35 hashsum.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11512 Sep 18 10:35 hdparm.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1848 Sep 18 10:35 hello.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3968 Sep 18 10:35 help.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4528 Sep 18 10:35 hexdump.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10528 Sep 18 10:35 hfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4408 Sep 18 10:35 hfspluscomp.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10792 Sep 18 10:35 hfsplus.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8944 Sep 18 10:35 http.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4504 Sep 18 10:35 iorw.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12560 Sep 18 10:35 iso9660.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8984 Sep 18 10:35 jfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8928 Sep 18 10:35 jpeg.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6424 Sep 18 10:35 keylayouts.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3144 Sep 18 10:35 keystatus.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8728 Sep 18 10:35 ldm.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  44560 Sep 18 10:35 legacycfg.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  15904 Sep 18 10:35 legacy_password_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12744 Sep 18 10:35 linux16.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10392 Sep 18 10:35 linuxefi.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  21552 Sep 18 10:35 linux.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4760 Sep 18 10:35 loadbios.mod
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     98 Sep 18 10:35 load.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9448 Sep 18 10:35 loadenv.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4816 Sep 18 10:35 loopback.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7248 Sep 18 10:35 lsacpi.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3272 Sep 18 10:35 lsefimmap.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5224 Sep 18 10:35 lsefi.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3568 Sep 18 10:35 lsefisystab.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2848 Sep 18 10:35 lsmmap.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6688 Sep 18 10:35 ls.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7368 Sep 18 10:35 lspci.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4136 Sep 18 10:35 lssal.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9536 Sep 18 10:35 luks.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9848 Sep 18 10:35 lvm.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12368 Sep 18 10:35 lzopio.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4856 Sep 18 10:35 macbless.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10952 Sep 18 10:35 macho.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2832 Sep 18 10:35 mdraid09_be.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2800 Sep 18 10:35 mdraid09.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2664 Sep 18 10:35 mdraid1x.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3192 Sep 18 10:35 memdisk.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4520 Sep 18 10:35 memrw.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5560 Sep 18 10:35 minicmd.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5688 Sep 18 10:35 minix2_be.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5592 Sep 18 10:35 minix2.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5656 Sep 18 10:35 minix3_be.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5576 Sep 18 10:35 minix3.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5616 Sep 18 10:35 minix_be.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5488 Sep 18 10:35 minix.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9648 Sep 18 10:35 mmap.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4810 Sep 18 10:35 moddep.lst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2231 Sep 18 10:35 modinfo.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3344 Sep 18 10:35 morse.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  44224 Sep 18 10:35 mpi.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3672 Sep 18 10:35 msdospart.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  21112 Sep 18 10:35 multiboot2.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  19104 Sep 18 10:35 multiboot.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6728 Sep 18 10:35 nativedisk.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  75112 Sep 18 10:35 net.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4544 Sep 18 10:35 newc.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10032 Sep 18 10:35 nilfs2.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 181456 Sep 18 10:35 normal.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5752 Sep 18 10:35 ntfscomp.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  15432 Sep 18 10:35 ntfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4384 Sep 18 10:35 odc.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2192 Sep 18 10:35 offsetio.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  16680 Sep 18 10:35 ohci.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2296 Sep 18 10:35 part_acorn.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2576 Sep 18 10:35 part_amiga.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2976 Sep 18 10:35 part_apple.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4192 Sep 18 10:35 part_bsd.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2616 Sep 18 10:35 part_dfly.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2152 Sep 18 10:35 part_dvh.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3232 Sep 18 10:35 part_gpt.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    111 Sep 18 10:35 partmap.lst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3032 Sep 18 10:35 part_msdos.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2528 Sep 18 10:35 part_plan.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2216 Sep 18 10:35 part_sun.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2448 Sep 18 10:35 part_sunpc.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     17 Sep 18 10:35 parttool.lst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7280 Sep 18 10:35 parttool.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2936 Sep 18 10:35 password.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4448 Sep 18 10:35 password_pbkdf2.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7560 Sep 18 10:35 pata.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2016 Sep 18 10:35 pbkdf2.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3464 Sep 18 10:35 pbkdf2_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3824 Sep 18 10:35 pcidump.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3848 Sep 18 10:35 play.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10600 Sep 18 10:35 png.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2200 Sep 18 10:35 priority_queue.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4376 Sep 18 10:35 probe.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3416 Sep 18 10:35 procfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2960 Sep 18 10:35 progress.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1984 Sep 18 10:35 raid5rec.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3216 Sep 18 10:35 raid6rec.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2264 Sep 18 10:35 read.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1840 Sep 18 10:35 reboot.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  78488 Sep 18 10:35 regexp.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14304 Sep 18 10:35 reiserfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25888 Sep 18 10:35 relocator.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5800 Sep 18 10:35 romfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7520 Sep 18 10:35 scsi.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5056 Sep 18 10:35 search_fs_file.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4992 Sep 18 10:35 search_fs_uuid.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4928 Sep 18 10:35 search_label.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5384 Sep 18 10:35 search.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14704 Sep 18 10:35 serial.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1026 Sep 18 10:35 setjmp.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2592 Sep 18 10:35 setjmp_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9056 Sep 18 10:35 setpci.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8008 Sep 18 10:35 sfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8728 Sep 18 10:35 signature_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3640 Sep 18 10:35 sleep.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3424 Sep 18 10:35 sleep_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3248 Sep 18 10:35 spkmodem.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9800 Sep 18 10:35 squash4.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  31040 Sep 18 10:35 syslinuxcfg.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4992 Sep 18 10:35 tar.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    162 Sep 18 10:35 terminal.lst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6816 Sep 18 10:35 terminal.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  20064 Sep 18 10:35 terminfo.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2040 Sep 18 10:35 test_blockarg.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4040 Sep 18 10:35 testload.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7864 Sep 18 10:35 test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3472 Sep 18 10:35 testspeed.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8192 Sep 18 10:35 tftp.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6584 Sep 18 10:35 tga.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2344 Sep 18 10:35 time.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2083 Sep 18 10:35 trig.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3640 Sep 18 10:35 tr.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1856 Sep 18 10:35 true.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11312 Sep 18 10:35 udf.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8032 Sep 18 10:35 ufs1_be.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7888 Sep 18 10:35 ufs1.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7888 Sep 18 10:35 ufs2.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10520 Sep 18 10:35 uhci.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5960 Sep 18 10:35 usb_keyboard.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  16088 Sep 18 10:35 usb.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11184 Sep 18 10:35 usbms.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3024 Sep 18 10:35 usbserial_common.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3496 Sep 18 10:35 usbserial_ftdi.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3792 Sep 18 10:35 usbserial_pl2303.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2320 Sep 18 10:35 usbserial_usbdebug.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5672 Sep 18 10:35 usbtest.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  19728 Sep 18 10:35 verify.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9024 Sep 18 10:35 video_bochs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9528 Sep 18 10:35 video_cirrus.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10096 Sep 18 10:35 video_colors.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  29608 Sep 18 10:35 video_fb.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5880 Sep 18 10:35 videoinfo.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     41 Sep 18 10:35 video.lst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9008 Sep 18 10:35 video.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3824 Sep 18 10:35 videotest_checksum.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5496 Sep 18 10:35 videotest.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8896 Sep 18 10:35 xfs.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  42792 Sep 18 10:35 xnu.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3264 Sep 18 10:35 xnu_uuid.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3320 Sep 18 10:35 xnu_uuid_test.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  20696 Sep 18 10:35 xzio.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8416 Sep 18 10:35 zfscrypt.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11400 Sep 18 10:35 zfsinfo.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  57576 Sep 18 10:35 zfs.mod
```

## `grub-install` and `update-grub`

I have now ran `sudo grub-install` followed by `sudo update-grub` the output is the following:

```
$ sudo grub-install
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-135-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-135-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

After I rebooted the system, still nothing!

Comment: Why not try a more current version than 14.04 ? 16.04 and 18.04 are both LTS versions.

Comment: I depend on 14.04 for my work, unfortunately. 14.04 used to work perfectly on this machine. I don't know what happened now and is not working ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have figured it out:

```
sudo apt-get download dpkg
sudo dpkg -i dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.8_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This will fix the problem.

Comment: made my life easier tnx ;]